# UserDetailsService does not get called during authentication in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, jwt

I have gone through the similar questions asked here, but none seems to tackle the problem I am facing right now.

I have actually implemented two different processes of jwt for spring boot, yet keep facing the same problem.

Here is the AuthenticationFilter that filters the request and performs the authentication. I have added log functions to narrate what part of the code does not get called. I have implemented a different approach and it still never gets called, and funnily enough, it gets called elsewhere, not just in the class that handles the authentication or the one called by the one that handles the authentication. I use Java 8, spring boot 2.6.5.

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);


    @Override protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                              FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                log.info(jwt + " first");
                String username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                log.info(username + " second");
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                log.info(userDetails + " third");
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                log.info(authToken + " fourth");
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please log in with your correct details.");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the log with "first" and the one with second get printed out, but the "third" doesn't. This is because `UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);` doesn't get called and the code doesn't throw an error. It just doesn't get called.

Here is the JwtUtils class

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);

    @Value("${jwt.secret:testing123}")
    String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.length:3600000}")
    long duration = 3600000;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication auth) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date()).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + duration))
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUsernameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid JWT signature: {}");
        }
}
```

Here is my CustomUserDetailsService

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

    String prefixRole = "ROLE_";

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if (employee == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such employee, bro.");
        }

        try {
            return User.withUsername(employee.getUsername()).password(employee.getPassword())
                    .authorities(getAllRoles(employee.getRoles())).accountExpired(false)
                    .accountLocked(false).credentialsExpired(false).disabled(false).build();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something bad happened and I don't know what it is.");
        }
    }
    
    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAllRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role: roles) {
            collection.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(prefixRole + role.getName()));
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

The entryPoint

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                   AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you step through the code with breakpoints at appropriate locations?

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't understand what you mean?